# How can I wrap text around an Image in a Scheme Slideshow?

Tags: image, scheme, racket, slideshow, pict

I'm trying to code a slideshow using Racket, and I want most of my images to be on the right hand side of my text.

So far I have the image where i want it, but all text afterwards ends up under the image to the left. I cant seem to get the text to occupy the same space as the image, just to the side of it. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75lUw.jpg).

Any help is appreciated. Code Below:

```
(slide
 (item #:align 'right (bitmap  "cyberdyne_behind_the_scenes.jpg"))

 (item "Artificial Intelligence")

 (item "Neural Network") 
 (para "   Processors" )

 (item "Advanced Robotics") 
 (para "   Systems for Medicine")

 (item "Consumer Products")

 (item "Defense"))
```

Comment: Maybe `hc-append` can be used? I don't have an elegant solution though.

Comment: For future reference, if anyone else needs help with this, i did use a combination of hc-append and vl-append to stick paragraphs together and put them next to images.

Answer (score 0):

I generally like to use `ppict` for this sort of thing.

You can find the documentation for ppict here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/unstable-gui/ppict.html

Using `((pslide-base-pict))` will give you a pict that is the size of your slide.

From there you can use `(coord ...)` to simply place what you want in the appropriate places.

Your slide would end up looking something like:

```
(slide
  (ppict-do ((pslide-base-pict))
            #:go (coord 1/2 0 'tc)
            <title>
            #:go (coord 1 1 'rb)
            <bottom-picture>
            #:go (coord 1/5 1/10 'tl)
            <bullets>))
```